# mongodb installation on fedora 23

Tags: mongodb, fedora-23

I tried installing `mongodb` on fedora 23 with following steps:

1. `dnf config-manager --add-repo https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.0/x86_64/`
2. `dnf install mongodb-org`

Second steps downloads the packages but gives error as:

> warning: /var/cache/dnf/repo.mongodb.org_yum_redhat_7_mongodb-org_3.0_x86_64_-f13c178f04772646/packages/mongodb-org-3.0.12-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 24f3c978: NOKEY
The downloaded packages were saved in cache till the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Public key for mongodb-org-3.0.12-1.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed

I'm using 64-bit fedora 23.

Comment: why don't you install mongodb from official fedora repository? `dnf install mongodb` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

To install mongodb and get it working on Fedora 25:

```
dnf install mongodb mongodb-server

systemctl start mongod

mongo
```

You might want to open port 27017 as well. We are sampling nano text editor today (-w tells it to create the file if it doesnt exist):

```
nano -w /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

add:

> -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT

```
service iptables restart
```